# How Can I Display a CSV File to an HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, papaparse

**EDIT:** My question isn't about enabling CORS

The ASP.Net Core Web API I've created takes one string parameter, then runs a command line utility and saves the output to a csv file. It then calls a few functions to format the csv file. Below is some sample data:

[CSV Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boTYo.png)

My API isn't hosted anywhere just yet. So for now I'm just running it using IIS Express in Visual Studio. The ultimate goal here is to use this API on a webpage where users can select a server from a form and once the form is submitted, it should automatically display the csv file to the webpage just like in the example above once the API has finished.

My problem starts with my Javascript code. When I submit the form on my webpage, I am getting the following errors in the console:

1. `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:36798/api/License/lmstat?serverName=28000%40txeappazu030' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
2. `script.js:11  GET http://localhost:36798/api/License/lmstat?serverName=28000%40txeappazu030 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)`
3. `Error fetching data:  TypeError: Failed to fetch  at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:11:32)`

Here is the Javascript code I'm using to call the API:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const selectedServer = document.getElementById('chosen_Server').value;
    
    //API URL
    const apiURL = 'http://localhost:36798/api/License/lmstat';

    try{
        const response = await fetch(`${apiURL}?serverName=${encodeURIComponent(selectedServer)}`);

        if (response.ok){
            const csvData = await response.text();
            console.log(csvData);
            //displayCSVData(csvData);
            //console.log('API Response: ', await response.text());
        }
        else{
            console.error('API Request Failed: ', response.status, response.statusText);
        }
    }
    catch (error){
        console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
    }
});
```

I'll also include my HTML below as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="readText.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame" id="frame">
        <div class="head-bar">
            <div class="server-wrapper">
                <form id="license-API" method="get" action="http://localhost:36798/api/License/lmstat">
                    <label for="server-list">Choose a Server:</label>
                        <select name="server-list" id="chosen_Server">
                            <option value="Server1">Server1</option>
                            <option value="Server2">Server2</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                        <label for="choose a file" class="fileLabel">Choose a File:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="inputFile" id="inputFile">
                        <pre id="output"></pre>
                </form>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <table id="table"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I first attempted to use `Papa.parse` after my Javascript, but there were two things wrong here:

1. The code should have been inserted in the `if(response.ok)` statement.
2. Papa.parse would return some errors in the console.

Then, I tried using `Papa.parse` inside the `if(response.ok` statement, but I run into the same 3 problems I outlined above.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the data you're fetching or how to parse/display it.  Have you looked up that CORS error message?  Is the server at `localhost:36798` configured to *allow* CORS?

Comment: @David, I would say that it isn't configured to allow CORS because I haven't changed any code in my API to do so.

Comment: Regarding the edit... *"My question isn't about enabling CORS"* - Then can you clarify what the question is about?  If you're not trying to solve a CORS problem, why are you asking about a CORS error?  Please take some time to clarify the problem.